# How do you use the Riemann surface of a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $S$ be a sheaf constructed from the germs of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and $S_0$ be one of its component.

$S_0$ is a Riemann surface and can be seen as the domain of a holomprhic function $f$.

How do you use this $S_0$, for example, the Riemann surface of $\log{z}$?

Comment: did you mean germs of holomorphic functions on opens subsets of $\Bbb C$ ?

Comment: yes, I meant that.

Comment: I really don't know what you are asking. Maybe you can put some definitions and try to explain where your problem is ?

Comment: 1. make germs $f_x$ from $(U, f)$, where $U$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is analytic on $U$. 2.define the topology on the set of these germs using $(U, f)$. 3. each connected component of that sheaf is a Riemann surface and the domain of a function.

Comment: The analytic continuation of $\log z =- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-z)^n}{n},|z-1| <1$ is $\{ L_n : U_n \to \mathbb{C},n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $U_n = \{ r e^{it}, r > 0, t \in [n/4-\pi/2,n/4+\pi/2]\}$, $L_0 = \log z$ on $|z-1| < 1 \subset U_0$, $L_{n+ 1}, L_{n-1}$ are the analytic continuations of $L_n$, and any analytic continuation of $L_0$ is contained in the $U_n,L_n$.